# Getting error when attempting to enable pretty URL's with Yii 2

Tags: php, apache, yii, yii2

I'm using `Yii 2` and I want to enable `pretty URL's` so that I can access stuff like:

```
www.example.com/controller/method
```

From what I found you add the below code in the *components* section of `config/web.php`:

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'enableStrictParsing' => true,
    'rules' => [

    ],
],
```

However when I load the index page I now get this error:

```
exception 'yii\base\InvalidRouteException' with message 'Unable to resolve the request: site/error' in *************\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Controller.php:122
```

There is also this previous exception:

```
exception 'yii\web\NotFoundHttpException' with message 'Page not found.' in ***************************\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Request.php:187
```

This is my `.htaccess` file:

```
# use mod_rewrite for pretty URL support
RewriteEngine on

# If a directory or a file exists, use the request directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Otherwise forward the request to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Am I missing something in the rules section or what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try removing 'enableStrictParsing' => true,

enableStrictParsing: this property determines whether to enable strict request parsing. If strict parsing is enabled, the incoming requested URL must match at least one of the rules in order to be treated as a valid request, or a yii\web\NotFoundHttpException will be thrown. If strict parsing is disabled, when none of the rules matches the requested URL, the path info part of the URL will be treated as the requested route.

Comment: you have no rules so none of them is ever matched

Comment: So I would have to specifically add a rule for each route I wanted and it wouldn't automatically work how I wanted?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I personally do not use enableStrictParsing, if a rule is not matched in the rules it will follow the normal path, controller/action.